# Question about Quran [2:30-36]

Tags: quran, tafseer

السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمْ وَرَحْمَةُ ٱللَّهِ وَبَرَكاتُهُ‎

بِسْمِ اللهِ الرَّحْمٰنِ الرَّحِيْمِ

ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّٰهِ I was reading Quran's surah 2 ( البقرة, 'al-Baqarah' ) today, when I came upon

> وَإِذْ قَالَ رَبُّكَ لِلْمَلَـٰٓئِكَةِ إِنِّى جَاعِلٌۭ فِى ٱلْأَرْضِ
> خَلِيفَةًۭ ۖ قَالُوٓا۟ أَتَجْعَلُ فِيهَا مَن يُفْسِدُ فِيهَا
> وَيَسْفِكُ ٱلدِّمَآءَ وَنَحْنُ نُسَبِّحُ بِحَمْدِكَ وَنُقَدِّسُ لَكَ
> ۖ قَالَ إِنِّىٓ أَعْلَمُ مَا لَا تَعْلَمُونَ ٣٠

Translated to:

> ˹Remember˺ when your Lord said to the angels, “I am going to place a successive ˹human˺ authority
> on earth.” They asked ˹Allah˺, “Will You place in it someone who will spread corruption there and
> shed blood while we glorify Your praises and proclaim Your holiness?” Allah responded, “I know
> what you do not know.

In this verse Allah Almighty (رَبُّكَ)  tells the angels (مَلَـٰٓئِكَةِ) that He is going to make a successive authority on earth/land (جَاعِلٌۭ فِى ٱلْأَرْضِ خَلِيفَةًۭ). In-short Allah is going to create humankind which will dwell upon earth.

But in the following verse :

> وَقُلْنَا يَـٰٓـَٔادَمُ ٱسْكُنْ أَنتَ وَزَوْجُكَ ٱلْجَنَّةَ وَكُلَا مِنْهَا رَغَدًا حَيْثُ شِئْتُمَا وَلَا تَقْرَبَا هَـٰذِهِ
> ٱلشَّجَرَةَ فَتَكُونَا مِنَ ٱلظَّـٰلِمِينَ ٣٥

Translated to :

> We cautioned, “O Adam! Live with your wife in Paradise and eat as freely as you please, but do not approach this tree, or else you will be wrongdoers.

Allah enjoys Adam and his wife a forever life in paradise (يَـٰٓـَٔادَمُ ٱسْكُنْ أَنتَ وَزَوْجُكَ ٱلْجَنَّةَ)  which is not earth  (ٱلْأَرْضِ).

But Satan/Iblis deceived them so they approached the tree (وَلَا تَقْرَبَا هَـٰذِهِ ٱلشَّجَرَةَ فَتَكُونَا مِنَ ٱلظَّـٰلِمِينَ) and then by Allah's will they were descended to earth as enemies of each other as humankind move on.

> فَأَزَلَّهُمَا ٱلشَّيْطَـٰنُ عَنْهَا فَأَخْرَجَهُمَا مِمَّا كَانَا فِيهِ ۖ وَقُلْنَا ٱهْبِطُوا۟ بَعْضُكُمْ لِبَعْضٍ عَدُوٌّۭ ۖ وَلَكُمْ فِى ٱلْأَرْضِ مُسْتَقَرٌّۭ وَمَتَـٰعٌ إِلَىٰ حِينٍۢ ٣٦

Translated to :

> But Satan deceived them—leading to their fall from the ˹blissful˺ state they were in, and We said, “Descend from the heavens ˹to the earth˺ as enemies to each other. You will find in the earth a residence and provision for your appointed stay.”

My Question :

So here is my question or say thought that Satan deceiving them was a necessity to fulfill Allah original plan which was told to angels referring to (verse 30) and secondly the more serious part " Why did Allah place them in heaven if they were originally planned to be successive authority upon earth? " .

I believe I am not worthy to question Allah's decision but in the Quran Allah says that he only speaks truth.

> قَالَ فَٱلْحَقُّ وَٱلْحَقَّ أَقُولُ ٨٤

I originally planned upon asking this question to my استاد/teacher but he has been sick for several days and is unable to lead Salat/prayer, I kindly request you all to make Du'a for his better health.

الله أعلم

جَزَاكَ ٱللَّٰهُ خَيْرًا

Comment: Allah does whatever He wills. He cannot be questioned. What are humans doing on earth when they are already destined for either paradise or hellfire.

Comment: @Riyaz this is something a person who doesn't know the answer would say. This is the same as saying Allah would know. I have already talked about the "He can not be questioned" argument by using verse 83 of Chapter Saad قَالَ فَٱلْحَقُّ وَٱلْحَقَّ أَقُولُ" ٨٤, lastly why am I being counter questioned when this is not a debate, the answer of your counter question is already in my question referring to 2:30, they are dwelling on earth because Allah planned a successive system upon earth which is finite and then afterlife occurs  which is never ending . الله أعلم

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allah placed Adam (AS) and his wife in heaven to test them with the tree.

Allah has complete knowledge of the future, so He knew they would eat from the tree.

Because of this knowledge, Allah told the angels they were successors on earth, because that was their intended destination in the first place.

Allah placed them in Jannah temporarily to test them and teach them how to repent from sin.

Allah never said they would live in Jannah forever.

Comment: positive, but most people use the statement : " Human dwell upon earth because of Adam A.S mistake otherwise they would have been heaven " . Which is wrong because Allah settled his original plan in 2:30 .

Comment: @help Whoever uses that statement is wrong.

Comment: Also see: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4736

Comment: جَزَاكَ ٱللَّٰهُ خَيْرًا